# code coverage calculation and profiling in VEINS/OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm trying to get code coverage and profiling information from my VEINS implementation using `gcov`/`llvm-cov` and `gprof`. What I have figured until now is I will have to change the Makefile to add the `--coverage -O0` and `-pg` for `gcov` and `gprof`, respectively. However, the build process for VEINS is a little complex for me to add this viz. `./configure` that calls `opp_makemake` and then run `make`. I would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OMNeT++ opp_makemake build system which Veins uses combines a variety of files into src/Makefile. If you want to adapt how the final Makefile looks, the easiest way I can think of is to modify src/makefrag, a fragment that gets included verbatim in the finished Makefile. An example is already included with Veins 5.0: https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/makefrag